# Clockwork Mod. To flash or not to flash?

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, rom-manager, droid-eris

Running: Verizon HTC Eris (No service) with the recommended Cyanogenmod for the device + Amon RA recovery as prescribed by the gscript lite method of rooting found in the "Universal Eris root for dummies" guide (the one with step by step pictures)

When i got the CM7 rom up and running i was looking through the preinstalled apps and found the rom manager. inside was the option "Flash ClockworkMod Recovery". From what iv gathered online (CWM > AmonRA)... Is this so? Should i use this option? I fear that by breaking my current recovery in an attempt to upgrade i will brick my device... Should i do this?

Comment: I don't think that the question as stated is entirely suitable  for _Android Enthusiasts_, because in the end it all falls to a matter of preference. Some people like CWM, others like AmonRa, and some like the new TWRP. Some recoveries function better on some devices. I think if you change your question to **"What is the difference between the different recovery options, and will they all wok for my device?"**, it will be better. For the record, I think [Liam W's recommendation below](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/38628/6072) is solid.

Comment: If you are interested [This thread on xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1842183) shows a good comparison of TWRP and CWM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely up to you, and your personal preference.

There is one thing I would suggest though: ***do not use ROM Manager***! It has a nasty history of damaged devices.

I would suggest that you go with either CWM or TWRP, if it is available for your device. I would suggest you flash it using fastboot, if it is available on your device.

If it isn't, then you should see forums such as [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com) for info on how to flash recovery images.

Comment: What is the difference between the 3 recoveries?